# Using EmojiMart in production in reactjs appliacation

Tags: reactjs, emoji

I'm trying to implement an emoji picker with a text input, I came across a package called [Emojimart](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart) it was really good and working effectively, but running it in production makes my bundle size too big, 
so I'm wondering if there is anyone who used it in production and if there is any tips on how to make it production ready?

**Or:** if there is any other alternatives.

**Note:** Reproducing what I have will take only 2 steps

1. Create react app with create-react-app
2. Install emojimart

Then check the bundle size and performance of the app, you will notice the difference.

Answer (score 2):

There was a discussion about that in the Emoji Mart project: https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart/issues/156 - unfortunately I don't see a solution that wouldn't require you to eject the app or use react-app-rewired.

Since you're using React, maybe you could give [emoji-picker-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-picker-react) a try. The bundle size in a new project is around 120 KB (80 KB gzipped).

Comment: I'm using react-app-rewired, what's the solution in this case, or even ejecting the app how's that gonna solve the problem

Comment: I'd suggest to avoid messing with the configuration too much. `emoji-picker-react` does all the things `emoji-mart` does while being more optimized.